# Saving image as PDF in overleaf creates problem

Tags: diagrams, overleaf, engineering

I know it would be considered irrelevant questions, however, I have to ask as I'm facing quite a trouble.  I have drawn figure in Visio and save as pdf and then using the figure in the overleaf projects. But every time there is a boarder line around the figure appears that makes me distract, below I'm sharing an example to clarify what I'm saying.Below red arrow presents the real problem
[image]

```
enter code here
```

\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{multirow}
%\renewcommand{\q}[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTCM2.jpg){``#1''}
%\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
%\strutlongstacks{T}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{array, caption, tabularx,  ragged2e,  booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{53}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabitem}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[tabitem]{wide=0pt, nosep, leftmargin= * ,label=\textendash,after=\vspace{-\baselineskip},before=\vspace{-0.6\baselineskip}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[t]
\includegraphics[ width=\linewidth]
{trils2.pdf}
\caption{ }
\label{firsta}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}

Comment: When you open the image file do you find this border? If yes, you can crop it using https://pdfresizer.com/crop.

Comment: Might be useful yo see your code. To tell if this is part of the image try wrapping the image in `\fbox{...}` as in `\fbox{\includegraphics....}`, this gives it a forced box and since this pox has a little padding inside it, you vcan more clearly see the borders of the actual image.

Comment: No I can't see in my PDF, this is the problem.  @daleif, I added Latex code over there, however, if I use fbox{} it makes another broader around figure.

Comment: Sorry, you are not providing any information that we can use you help you. I've added the `overleaf` tag as it seems appropriate

Comment: what kind of information you want, tell me, I'm here to solve the problem as it gives stress,

Comment: You need to provide us with a full code that others can test. I cannot use `\begin{figure*}[t] ...` for anything, I don't even know which document class you are using. First of all, does your overleaf document even compile without errors? indidated by a red button/marker next to the green compile button.

Comment: Now added document class as you said, and Yes It has some errors which it shows, but I don't understand the questions that you asked has some relation with my problem?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: @daleif sorry, the tag was on here earlier but I removed it. Because with the given information at the time, it was most likely that the image file had a border on it. It looks like OP hasn't shared the actual image file itself, so it's still impossible to know if it is Overleaf-related or not. Did I miss the image file somewhere? Here's the OP's code in Overleaf, the only change is I used a borderless PDF from the MWE package since I don't have the OP's PDF: https://www.overleaf.com/read/ykbpyzwbwpnf . No errors and no border is being added. So more info is needed, namely the PDF file itself.

Comment: DG', I couldn't understand what you said can explain it.  @Paul I used your file but you didn't upload any figure, you used built-in figure code. If I send you a pdf image can you check that? or if you allow me to upload figure in your file then you might see border around it

Comment: @Shane yes, I can't upload your figure because as I mentioned, I don't have it. You didn't provide the file anywhere for anyone to access. If you want others to see your actual PDF file, you can upload it to Dropbox or similar and add a public link in the comments here. Alternatively, post a read-only link to your Overleaf project (but only if you are OK with others viewing your project).

Comment: But what I'm thinking is that right now I can only share with you in order to show because you shared overleaf file with me, for other guys I already shared image to understand my question, what do you think?

Comment: @Shane you shared a screenshot of the output from Overleaf. This shows the problem but doesn't let us figure out exactly what's causing it. What we need is the actual PDF file that you exported from Visio and are using in your Overleaf project, so we can determine if there's something unique about the PDF file in conjunction with your code that's causing the border to appear.

Comment: Okay, I understand, one thing to let you know that the file generated from Visio which is PDF file when I open it in PDF formate it has no borders but when the same PDF file is used in overleaf the borders appear as shown in the figure.  I'm also confused about the casue of this problem that's why asking